# Check if string contains regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of text and I'm looking to check if the string contains a certain pattern. i.e. [Ref:number/number/number]

```
var myStr = "This is a string [Ref:1234/823/2]";  //Yes, has regex pattern
var myStr2 = "This is another sample string"; //No, regex pattern not present
```

Any ideas what the regex is for this pattern is: [Ref:1234/823/2]?

The words Ref will always be present followed by a colon, then 3 groups of digits separated by a forward slash and will be contained within square brackets.

```
[Ref:<digits>/<digits>/<digits>]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: It is rather a basic regex in fact. What pattern did you come up with?

Comment: [Off topic - meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083)  TLDR; this isn't a programming problem, it's a task and you're asking someone else to do it for you.  This is of no lasting benefit to anyone but you (or anyone with a need for this exact regex).  If you have a regex that is not doing what you expect, by all means, show us what you've written and explain why the behaviour is not as you expected.

Comment: He didn't ask for a regex expression, he asked a way to check if the text has a regex expression.

Comment: @Afonso He asked for a regex to check if there is this pattern in his string: "[Ref:<digits>/<digits>/<digits>]". He even wrote "Any ideas what the regex is..."

Comment: I think he did ask for a regex, the title is just confusing this should work 
    \\[Ref:\d+\/\d+\/\d+\\]

Comment: @HansKilian Only the `[` must be escaped. `]` is not "special" outside of a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args){

        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[Ref:(-?[0-9]+)/(-?[0-9]+)/(-?[0-9]+)\]");       
        string text = "This is a string [Ref:1234/823/2]";
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
            int first_value = Int32.Parse(groups[1].Value);
            int second_value = Int32.Parse(groups[2].Value);
            int third_value = Int32.Parse(groups[3].Value);
        }
    }
```

(edit) if you don't need the values:

```
    static void Main(string[] args){
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[Ref:(-?[0-9]+)/(-?[0-9]+)/(-?[0-9]+)\]");       
        string text = "This is a string [Ref:1234/823/2]";
        bool matched = rx.IsMatch(text);
    }
```

Comment: OP needs a boolean output, see *Yes, has regex pattern* and  *No, regex pattern not present*.

Comment: Probably it should be `if (rx.IsMatch(...))`

Answer (score 0):

I do not worked in `c#`, sometime this pattern will help you to find that.

```
[Ref:[\d+/\d+/\d]+]
```

[Demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5bRef%3a%5b%5cd%2b%2f%5cd%2b%2f%5cd%5d%2b%5d&i=This+is+a+string+%5bRef%3a1234%2f823%2f2%5d)

Comment: [`\[Ref:[\d/]+]` matches `[Ref:///////////////////]`](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/17). And `/[Ref:[\d+\/\d+\/\d\]+]/` is a typo since C# patterns should never be used within regex delimiters. The `/` is not a special char in .NET patterns, do not escape it.

Comment: My mistake. Please check I have edited it. As i said in I'm not worked i `c#`. In my known programming language `/` need to be escaped.

Comment: What you posted in the answer does not match your demo. Please fix. Actually, OP does not know how to use regex patterns, I think the answer will be complete with the C# regex checking method example (since you are "spoon-feeding", it is fair to expect full answer) .

Comment: See [what your solution matches in .NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%5bRef%3a%5b%5cd%2b%5c%2f%5cd%2b%5c%2f%5cd%5c%5d%2b%5d%2f&i=%2fR%2f+This+is+a+string+%5bRef%3a1234%2f823%2f2%5d). Regex101 is not .NET regex compatible, so any "demo here" with regex101 cannot be a proof your solution works in a .NET environment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thank you for that link. Can you recheck

Comment: An upvote for `[Ref:[\d+/\d+/\d]+]`? It is a really wrong pattern now.